# db.logIn is not a function

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

when trying to access the login of couchDb from HTML-Script file, its throwing error like this, any solution ?

> ```
> Error is =>script.js:89 Uncaught TypeError: rdb.logIn is not a function
>
> const rdb = 'http://localhost:5984/r' 
> rdb.logIn('admin', 'password')
> ```

Comment: There's not enough context in this post for anyone to provide an answer.  The code line `const rdb = 'http://localhost:5984/r' rdb.logIn('admin', 'password')` is completely incorrect javascript code. A minimal reproducible code example is needed.

Comment: const rdb = 'http://localhost:5984/r3'

rdb.logIn('admin', 'password').then( () => { console.log('loggedin') } ).catch( (err) => { console.log(err) } )

Comment: What is `rdb` ?

Comment: rdb is remote database which is yet to be created in couchDb at remote location

Comment: `rdb` is not a remote database, it's a [Javascript string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) literal, representative of a URL.  Go through a basic Javascript intro, then go through the pages found at [https://pouchdb.com/guides](https://pouchdb.com/guides/). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we used the `PouchDBAuthentication` plugin.

```js
import PouchDB from "pouchdb-browser";
import PouchDBAuthentication from "pouchdb-authentication";

PouchDB.plugin(PouchDBAuthentication);

const database = new PouchDB(
  'remote-database-url',
  {
    ajax: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
    fetch(url, opts) {
      opts.credentials = "include";
      return fetch(url, opts);
    },
  } as PouchDB.Configuration.RemoteDatabaseConfiguration
);

const username = 'your username';
const password = 'your password';

const ajaxOpts = {
  ajax: {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Basic " + window.btoa(username + ":" + password),
    },
  },
};

database.login(username, password, ajaxOpts).then((res) => console.log('logged in', res));
```